# clicking on angular mat-chip selected not firing valueChanges and chip value is not available in valueChanes event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-chip-list with multiple mat-chips. but when I click on the mat-chip they are no firing the valueChanges event and valueChanges event fired by other controls don't have the value of the select chips too.

here is the code.

```
<mat-chip-list aria-label="{{question.key}} selection" [selectable]=true>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
                      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="opt.value">
                        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'No'">
                          <mat-basic-chip class="mat-basic-chip-no" [value]="opt.key" #lbl="matChip"
                            (click)="chipControlOnSelect(question.key,opt.key,fi,fgi, lbl)">
                            {{opt.value}}</mat-basic-chip>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                          <mat-basic-chip [value]="opt.key" #lbl="matChip"
                            (click)="chipControlOnSelect(question.key,opt.key,fi,fgi, lbl)">
                            {{opt.value}}</mat-basic-chip>
                        </ng-container>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                  </mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: have u tried aading ngmodel like this [(ngModel)] = ''modelname"

Comment: should have mentioned, these controls are in template form.

Answer (score -1):

```
(click)="chipControlOnSelect(opt.key)"
[value]="opt.key"
```

In the above statement, may be following changes can help to get the values.

```
(click)="chipControlOnSelect($event)"
[value]="opt.newkey"
```

combine all the parameters (question.key,opt.key,fi,fgi, lbl) with a pipe symbol and store it in the 'opt.newKey'

```
chipControlOnSelect(event: any){
  let newKey = event.target.value;
  --- here you can split the values by using pipe symbol and get the required values.

}
```

Comment: but i need the values in valueChange event of the form